# mobilefirst 7.1 authentication not working

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

*EDIT: An IBM Employee visited us today to have a look at this problem as well. 
We did not solve the problem, but we think the root of the problem is something else. So I will rewrite the problem description.

The server was refusing connection due to the appAuthenticityTest failing. So for now we disabled the appAuthenticityTest to test the server configuration.

But we are now seeing the following errors in the log:

```
[3/4/16 16:12:06:529 CET] 000000a4 LoginContext  E com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'wl_authenticityLoginModule' failed. Missing app authenticity configuration parameters. [project mapruntime]
                                 com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Missing app authenticity configuration parameters
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.appauth.AuthenticityAuthenticatorImpl.processRequest(AuthenticityAuthenticatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.AuthenticityAuthenticator.processRequest(AuthenticityAuthenticator.java:79)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:212)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:779)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:679)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:652)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:81)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:717)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:413)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1073)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)

[3/4/16 16:12:06:537 CET] 000000a4 LoginContext  E com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule wl_authenticityLoginModule, User Identity Not available. [project mapruntime] [project mapruntime]
```

My application-descriptor.xml contains:

```
<android securityTest="MAPCertLogin" version="1.0.4">
  <worklightSettings include="false"/>
  <pushSender key="**********" senderId="******"/>
  <compressWebResources enabled="true"/>
</android>
<common securityTest="MAPCertLogin"/>
```

My authenticationConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
             5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
             US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
             disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->
    <!---->
    <!--  Sample security tests  
         Even if not used there will be some default webSecurityTest and mobileSecurityTest 
         Attention: if using <testAppAuthenticity/> test below ,<publicSigningKey> element must be added to application-descriptor.xml as well. -->
    <securityTests>
        <mobileSecurityTest name="MAPCertLogin">    
            <testUser realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>   
            <testDirectUpdate mode="perRequest"/>
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="custom" realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>
            <!--  testAppAuthenticity  -->
        </mobileSecurityTest>
     <!--      
        <customSecurityTest name="PushSecurityTest">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>
            <test isInternalDeviceID="true" realm="MAPLoginRealm" />
        </customSecurityTest>
        -->
    </securityTests>
    <realms>
        <realm loginModule="StrongDummy" name="SampleAppRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>
        <realm loginModule="MAPLoginModule" name="MAPLoginRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAutoProvisioningAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="validate-csr-function" value="Authenticator.validateCSR"/>
        </realm>
    </realms>
    <loginModules>
        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
        <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="MAPLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule</className>
            <parameter name="validate-certificate-function" value="Authenticator.validateCertificate"/>
        </loginModule>
    </loginModules>
</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

Why do we get the "Missing app authenticity configuration parameters" error while having the appAuthenticityTest disabled?

Regards,
Stijn

Comment: Run the server in trace mode and provide the logs. What you say is "not useful" may be useful. As it is there is nothing in the question to progress it further.

Comment: Which traces do you want me to set? I did set it to *=all and I ended up with a log of 7.5mb in 4 minutes. How do you want me to share the log with you? Will it contain information which should not be publicly shared openly over the internet?

Comment: I have no idea. review the log to see if it contain something which should not be there. You can upload it to any file hosting service - google drive and the like. If you don't want it shared then I suggest to remove this question and open a PMR instead.

Comment: stop the server once the error is encountered in order to reduce log size.

Comment: You mention - "server refusing connection due to the appAuthenticityTest failing. So for now we disabled the appAuthenticityTest to test the server configuration."
a) When you had the appauthenticityTest , did you have the public signing key added to the application-descriptor?
b) After you commented out the appauthenticityTest, did you redeploy the runtime and restart the server for the changes to take effect?

Comment: A) Yes, we did create a public signing key, B) Yes, just confirmed, a restart of the server does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error happens because you are also trying to implement Custom Device Provisioning, however device provisioning requires authenticity... so either fix your authenticity setup per the Application Authenticity tutorial, or remove the device provisioning definition as well.